# How can I reduce a tensor's last dimension in PyTorch?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have tensor of shape `(1, 3, 256, 256, 3)`. I need to reduce one of the dimensions to obtain the shape `(1, 3, 256, 256)`. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Reduce dimension how?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, in numpy I would use `squeeze`, but what should I use for this in pytorch?

Comment: In NumPy, even with squeeze, it won't give you the expected dimensionality.

Comment: @Divakar Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to specify how you want to reduce each of the three values in the last dimension to one. You may add them up, average them or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to apply mean over the last dimension, then you can do so with:

```
In [18]: t = torch.randn((1, 3, 256, 256, 3))

In [19]: t.shape
Out[19]: torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 256, 3])

# apply mean over the last dimension
In [23]: t_reduced = torch.mean(t, -1)

In [24]: t_reduced.shape
Out[24]: torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 256])

# equivalently
In [32]: torch.mean(t, t.ndimension()-1).shape
Out[32]: torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 256])
```